# Find Service Name in Azure?

Tags: powershell, azure

How do I find the service name in Azure? I'm simply trying to schedule a shut down for a VM using Azure powershell, and the service name is required. All search results are outdated and do not apply to the new Azure portal. The classic portal is not configured with my instance of Azure. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by classic portal is not configured with my instance of azure ?

Comment: You can access the old portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com There is also a tile in your dashboard that links to it, called "Azure classic portal" (unless you deleted it, of course).

Comment: @Atf here's a screenshot of the classic portal for me: https://s3.postimg.io/xl603s6qr/Classic.png There's nothing setup in there, but when I go to the new portal everything is there.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer. I needed to login to the resource manager using Login-AzureRmAccount. Once logged in to stop the VM: Stop-AzureRmVM -Name "VMName" -ResourceGroupName "GroupName"

I was being thrown off by the classic way to do it: Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName "ServiceName" -Name "VMName"

Comment: ARM and ASM are different approach. Almost every powershell cmdlets are different for ASM and ARM, apart from some storage related cmdlets which are same in both.